# How to configure Windows Server 2012 Firewall to block this bot attack?

Tags: brute-force

My Windows logs are flooded with what looks like a brute force attack on my machine. I want to be able to block these ports from the outside, but I'm not certain what service this is and what port this is. Does anyone know how I would need to configure my firewall to block this inbound traffic?

```
An account failed to log on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x0

Logon Type:         3

Account For Which Logon Failed:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       administrator
    Account Domain:     

Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     Unknown user name or bad password.
    Status:         0xC000006D
    Sub Status:     0xC000006A

Process Information:
    Caller Process ID:  0x0
    Caller Process Name:    -

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   -
    Source Network Address: 120.78.194.44
    Source Port:        50983

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      NtLmSsp 
    Authentication Package: NTLM
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   -
    Key Length:     0
```

Comment: What services are you providing?

Comment: This is a web server only (IIS). I cannot tell from this error what service the attacker is coming in on. There's a source port but no destination port in the logs.

Comment: The attacker's IP is in an Asia-Pacific block.  Depending on whether you have legitimate traffic coming from that region you might want to just block the whole range.

Comment: Problem is, every entry is a different ip address / subnet. I'm wondering if I can just block the the service except for internal traffic. I'm thinking this might be SMB? I can't really tell.

Comment: These are not the helpful logs. What do your firewall logs say? Why not simply block anything but the ***ports you actually want to expose***?